# C++ ¿puedo declarar un objeto de una clase como tipo de dato de un pair?

Tags: c++, poo, objeto, compilador, pair

¿en C++ se puede declarar un objeto de una clase como tipo de dato de un pair? He estado buscando pero no he encontrado mucho, lo he intentado aplicar en mi código pero no sale, ej:

Este es el código:

```
char tag ='A';            



 point p(p.get_x(),p.get_y());


    Nodo a(p,0);

    pair<Nodo&,char> nodo1; //donde me sale el error
    nodo1.first = a;
    nodo1.second= tag;
```

Y este es el error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<Nodo&, char>::pair()’
         pair<Nodo&,char> nodo1;
                          ^~~~~
```

Tengo declaradas todas las librerías necesarias.

Se agradece ayuda,gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que el primer tipo del par es una referenca. Dado que no puedes crear referencias y no asignarles valor, como estás usando el constructor por defecto de nodo (constructor sin parámetros) la referencia no está obteniendo valor y el constructor falla.

Prueba esto:

```
pair<Nodo&,char> nodo1{a, tag};
```